# Nav bar change content (html / js)

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, navbar

I have this example code from w3schools ( https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_fixed_menu ) and i don't know how to change the page's content when i click the buttons ( Home , News , Contact ) what i wamted is to mimic the normal website where there is a home then you click contact and the url goes from `http://website.com` to `http://website.com/contact`

Comment: If you want all info displayed in one page without redirections and page refreshes then look at **Single Page Applications**.

Comment: and what if i want to make with redirections?

Comment: In that case you need to create those pages (home.html, news.html, contact.html).
Why you want to mimic normal behavior of a site, and not to make the site as it should be?

Comment: that works for me but when i load the page it shows the url like domain.com/contacts.html and i only wanted it to show domain.com/contacts

Comment: It's called [clean url](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL). To broad of a topic dependent on the technology used.